# Parsing GraphQL output in R

Tags: r, graphql

I am attempting to parse GraphQL syntax in R, and am not finding a great place to start.

The data comes in as one character string that looks like the following:

```
"{\"data\":{\"boards\":[{\"items\":[{\"name\":\"Fred\",\"column_values\":[{\"title\":\"Career Tag\",\"text\":\"analyst\"}]},{\"name\":\"Jon\",\"column_values\":[{\"title\":\"Career Tag\",\"text\":\"barista\"}]}]}]},\"account_id\":12345}
```

The ultimate output should look something like this:

```
Name   Career_Tag
Fred   analyst
Jon    barista
```

Is there a package to handle this transformation easily? I have tried `graphql2json` but keep getting this error:

`Error in dump_json_ast(input, parse_schema) : 
  1.2-7: syntax error, unexpected STRING`

Comment: The response is already a JSON string. You would parse it like any JSON string. The fact that it's being returned by a GraphQL service is irrelevant.

Comment: I know it's already in JSON, but yes that is effectively my question. It's nearly impossible to parse in this format.

Comment: have you tried the jsonlite package in R? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html